# case-sensitive list sorting, but just the duplicate values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, sorting

I have a list of strings like this:
`['A', 'b','C','adam','ADam','EVe','eve','Eve','d','Adam']`

I need to sort only the duplicate values **only** in string order to get output as
`['A', 'b','C','ADam','Adam','adam','EVe','Eve','eve','d']`

Here 'ADam','Adam','adam' were originally at different places in the list, but by standard ordering, they should be like this. Hence when the sorting method sees 'adam', it should try to find duplicates, sort and reorder the list as in the output for all adam's(Case Sensitive Order)
Please note all the other values remain as is. i.e 'A', 'b','C','d' all remain in original positions

I am able to do a standard sort or write complex code to do this work but I am looking for some existing and optimal mechanism as this list can be huge (Billions of records).So efficiency is crucial

Any ideas or pointers to existing library of code snippets helps
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the actual rules for your sort? Why is adam after C?

Comment: If you can clearly define your rules, you can make a key function

Comment: The rule is to order the duplicate values only, in the given example `adam,ADam,EVe,eve,Eve,Adam` are the candidates as they are the duplicate values in the list.
Then it should find the first entry i.e adam and EVe order them properly and relocate ordered values to first match 

`adam -->  ADam,Adam,adam at index 3,4,5`

So list becomes `['A', 'b','C','ADam','Adam','adam','EVe','eve','Eve','d']`
Then again
`eve --> EVe,Eve,eve at index 6.7.8`
So list becomes
`['A', 'b','C','ADam','Adam','adam','EVe','Eve','eve','d']`

As `A,b,C,d` don't have duplicates, they should not be touched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = ["A", "b", "C", "adam", "ADam", "EVe", "eve", "Eve", "d", "Adam"]

tmp = {}
for i, word in enumerate(map(str.lower, lst)):
    if word not in tmp:
        tmp[word] = i

lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda w: (tmp[w.lower()], w))
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
['A', 'b', 'C', 'ADam', 'Adam', 'adam', 'EVe', 'Eve', 'eve', 'd']
```

---

A benchmark comparing mine and others answers:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

lst = ["A", "b", "C", "adam", "ADam", "EVe", "eve", "Eve", "d", "Adam"]


def sort_1(lst):
    tmp = {}
    for i, word in enumerate(map(str.lower, lst)):
        if word not in tmp:
            tmp[word] = i

    lst.sort(key=lambda w: (tmp[w.lower()], w))
    return lst


def sort_2(s):
    return s.iloc[np.lexsort([s, pd.factorize(s.str.lower())[0]])]


def sort_3(lst):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for word in lst:
        d[word.casefold()].append(word)
    return list(chain.from_iterable(map(sorted, d.values())))


t1 = timeit("sort_1(l)", setup="l = lst*10_000", number=1, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit(
    "sort_2(s)", setup="s = pd.Series(lst*10_000)", number=1, globals=globals()
)
t3 = timeit("sort_3(l)", setup="l = lst*10_000", number=1, globals=globals())

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
```

Prints on my machine Python 3.9/AMD 3700x:

```
0.04896668600849807
0.05656355991959572
0.015082631958648562
```

Comment: Thanks this works :) But is it possible to have a faster way to do this?

Comment: @PradeeptaDinda You can try @Mozway's answer, but it seems plain `.sort()` is quicker.

Comment: Could you add mine to your benchmark as well?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Done. It's clearly fastest :)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't entirely expect that

Comment: Thank you all for the help.I appreciate it a lot 

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas`+`numpy`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l = ['A', 'b','C','adam','ADam','EVe','eve','Eve','d','Adam']

s = pd.Series(l)

s.iloc[np.lexsort([s, pd.factorize(s.str.lower())[0]])]
```

Output:

```
0       A
1       b
2       C
4    ADam
9    Adam
3    adam
5     EVe
7     Eve
6     eve
8       d
dtype: object
```

Comment: I've added small benchmark to compare our answers. I thought yours will be quicker, but apparently not (maybe I've made mistake in the benchmark).

Comment: @Andrej I'm not highly surprised. There are a few layers of overhead in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that python dictionaries are ordered as of version 3.6:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

d = defaultdict(list)
for word in lst:
    d[word.casefold()].append(word)
result = list(chain.from_iterable(map(sorted, d.values())))
```